# How can JQuery use a model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
   {
        <fieldset>
    <p>
    <label for="Title">Referans Adı</label>
    <p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=> Model.Name)
    </p>
```

How can the model's data be used in javascript like used in the html form?

Can javascript use the model data like used in html from?(like Model.Name)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Razor can parse the following just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("@Model.Name");
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" gives this error.

Comment: @mgnfcnt, That means that your Model is null. Have you set the Model properly?

Comment: @mgnfcnt, where did you place this code? Make sure it is after you've loaded jQuery.

Comment: Can I assign this Name value to a variable?

Comment: @Brandon 'var a = @Model.Name;' this does not work. Says "conditional compilation is turned off"

Comment: @Mgnfcnt, run it anyways. It'll still work, that is just a warning.

Comment: @Mgnfcnt put "@Model.Name" between quotes like this: var a = "@Model.Name"; and it works and doesn't give the error

Comment: It's a lot cleaner to not embed the JavaScript directly in the page like that, of course, and instead to fetch the model from the server via Ajax, or by generating the JS file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the javascript in a separate .js file instead of in your view, you can use a hidden field to store the value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name-hidden" value="@Model.Name" />
```

You can then access it in javascript by using the id.  For instance, in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready({
    var $nameHidden = $('#name-hidden');
    alert('Old Name: ' + $nameHidden.val());

    $nameHidden.val('Some New Name');
    alert('New Name: ' + $nameHidden.val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Some prefer you actually shouldn't do it this way and instead load your model as JSON and use those javascsript elements directly in your script and not razor syntax. The razor parser sometimes throws errors during compile/design (not at run time since I believe it's just related to intellisense) when you include @whatever inside of a  block.

Comment: Wish I could give this more than just +1.

Answer (score 1):

for those of us who are still using .aspx in some old projects:

```
alert("<%= Model.OrderStatus %>");
```